# Find if $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\ln{x}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I need to find if $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\ln{x}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx$ converges or diverges.
I have already tried to replace $\ln{x}$ for $x-1$.
Still, that gave me no result and I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Do a limit comparison test with $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}} dx$$ Since $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln x/\sqrt x}{\ln x/\sqrt{\sin x}}=1$$ one of the integrals converges iff the other integral converges.
(ii) Integrate $$\int_a^\pi \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}} dx$$
by parts. $$\int_a^\pi \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}} dx=\int_a^\pi (2\sqrt x)'\ln x dx$$ $$=2\sqrt x \ln x|_a^{\pi}-2\int_a^\pi \frac{\sqrt x}{x}dx$$ $$=2\sqrt \pi \ln \pi-2\sqrt a \ln a-2\int_a^\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx$$ $$=2\sqrt \pi \ln \pi-2\frac{\ln a}{1/\sqrt a}-4\sqrt \pi +4\sqrt a $$ The limit of the fraction as $a \to 0^+$ can be found by l'Hospital's Rule. The limit of $\sqrt a$ is 0. So the integral converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sin(x)\approx x$ near the origin. More precisely,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1
$$
So, if you multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x}$, you need only look at
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}} dx,
$$
which might be more manageable, to study the behavior at $0$.

Comment: What do you denote $\approx\:$?

Comment: I meant close to. That was really an intuitive motivation, thee relevant fact is that the first displayed quotient tends to $1$ when $x\to 1$.

Comment: Are you a physicist?

Comment: No, I am not. Why? I was trying to provide some intuition

Comment: I can understand, but it can be dangerous. The rigourous notion is  that of equivalent functions near $0$, because there's a theorem for equivalent functions: for improper integrals of equivalent functions near a bound of integration, both converge or both diverge

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I included the limit of the quotient being $1$ as the rigorous fact to aid in the argument.